# Flexbox: how to wrap a flex item once the width of another flex item is 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-position

I got a flex container that contains 2 elements. Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h4b2xvsf/28/). The first one is a **dynamic** header with text. The second one is a wrapper for multiple **dynamic** buttons. Dynamic meaning the text is generated with javascript and does not have a specific `width` and there can be 2-4 buttons depending on the user (so I cannot set `flex-basis` or `width` to a specific amount of `px` on these flex-items).

I have set the overflow of the text to `hidden` and the `text-overflow` property to `ellipsis`.

Now I would like for the buttons to wrap to a new line **only** when the text has completely dissapeared. This is what I mean:

[image]

[This article](https://mastery.games/post/flex-wrap/) has led me to believe it has something to do with the `flex-basis` property.

> The first gotcha with flex-wrap is that flex items will only begin to wrap if their sum total flex-basis is greater than the size of the flex container.

However, whatever properties I try, I cannot seem to get it to work how I want to.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  /* Only wrap once the text is fully gone and not visible anymore. */
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.actions button:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet constructeur
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button>
      button1
    </button>
    <button>
      button2
    </button>
    <button>
      button3
    </button>
    <button>
      button4
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this by using a big `flex-shrink` on the first container. This will give more priority to the first container for the shrink effect.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-shrink:99999;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap:10px; /* you can use gap with flexbox*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet constructeur
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button>
      button1
    </button>
    <button>
      button2
    </button>
    <button>
      button3
    </button>
    <button>
      button4
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify all the code like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  flex-basis:0;
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
}


.actions {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap:10px; /* you can use gap with flexbox*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet constructeur
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button>
      button1
    </button>
    <button>
      button2
    </button>
    <button>
      button3
    </button>
    <button>
      button4
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool solution, thanks. Could you explain what you mean with `This will give more priority to the first container for the shrink effect`?

Comment: @Reinier68 initially both will have the same shrink factor (1) so they will shrink the same way. If you give a big number to the first one it will shrink more. I have added another idea without flex-shrink and less code

Comment: Ahh allright, clear. I've tried your other solution aswell. However, that breaks the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property.

Comment: @Reinier68 no it doesn't, I have update the HTML as well